# Observable Collection not updating the UI

Tags: observablecollection

I've read a dozen topics here, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have an ObservableCollection, I can add new Employees, but the UI is not displaying the changes right away. If I stop, and restart, the changes show up.

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
  {
    DataAccess.EmployeeRepository repository = new DataAccess.EmployeeRepository();
private ObservableCollection<Employee> employees;

public MainViewModel()
{
  employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(repository.GetEmployees());
}


public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
{
  get { return employees; }
  set
  {
    employees = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Employees");
  }
}
```

My XAML has the following binding:

```
<ListView Name="ListViewEmployeeDetails" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,109,12,23"  ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentEmployee}"  >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="grdTest">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeID}"  Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeName}"  Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Phone" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeePhone}" Width="100" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I can't figure out what is wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainViewModel()
{
  Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(repository.GetEmployees());
}
```

You have to set `Employees` since you're firing the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event on its setter.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. Listview is still not refreshing.

Comment: I was adding to the repository, but not the ObservableCollection.

Can you tell me if the following approach is acceptable:

      Employee e = new Employee();
      e.EmployeeName = "New Employee";
      e.DepartmentID = 1;
      repository.AddEmployee(e);
      Employees.Add(e);

Comment: Did you set the DataContext in the code-behind file? And yes, you'll need to populate the observablecollection somehow.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I don't want to have to add to the repository AND the ObservableCollection.  Seems I should only have to add to one or the other.